# Installing XCode on a Mac from USB

Tags: xcode, macos, usb-drive

I've got access to an old Macbook, and I want to install XCode on it but it's only got 40GB free space (it's 120GB and the other files are important, so I can't remove them). I have a downloaded .xip of XCode and I want to install it, but the xip is 10GB and XCode needs more than 30GB to install.

I moved the .xip file to a USB and tried to install from there (by double-clicking on the .xip), but it through a "no such file or directory" error at the end of the unzip process.
Is this a known problem? And if not, can someone tell me how to find the logs on a Mac so I can see what was actually going on? I haven't used Apple anything for 10 years and I can't seem to find anything.